# How to clear cin Buffer in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, buffer, cin

I have gone through many existing answers here StackOverflow, but I am still stuck.

code:

```
int c;
cin >> c;

if(cin.fail()) {
   cout << "Wrong Input";
   cin.clear();
   cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
}
else
{
   cout << c*2;   
}
```

If I enter wring input e.g `s` instead of an integer, it outputs `Wrong Input`. However, if I enter an integer, and then I enter a string, it ignores the string and keep outputting the previous integer result, hence it does not clears the cin buffer, and the old value of `c` keeps on executing.
Can anyone please suggest the best way other than `cin.ignore()` as it does not seem to work. 
and yeah for me, the max() in `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` gives error. So this does not work either.

Comment: Why don't you ask a question to get the correct way to do this working?  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction) is the correct way to handle the situation.

Comment: Can you make your question clearer (e.g. providing a [MCVE]). I can't spot what shouldn't work with your code. I can't get it even to [compile](http://ideone.com/Syb32Q)

Comment: @NathanOliver This gives me error `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()` the max() function gives me error `#define max(a,b) (((a) > (b))) ? (a) : (b))` even if I define this statement in my file. 

@πάνταῥεῖ I will try to upload a video I think that might be more clear.

Comment: Do you have in your code `#define max(a,b) (((a) > (b))) ? (a) : (b))` or do you include a header that has that in it?

Answer (score 1):

the max() function needs to be defined in the beginning of the file. `cin.ignore()` works very well to clear the buffer, however you need the numeric limits function max(), which in my case was giving error.

Solution:

```
#ifdef max
#define max
#endif
```

add these lines on the top, and a function such as following will work fine.

```
int id;
bool b;
do {
    cout << "Enter id: ";
    cin >> id;
    b = cin.fail();
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
} while ( b == true);
```

P.S: Thanks @Nathan